# How to get entire tag as String from an XML

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

The problem here is that I am getting different xml's with different namespaces everytime.

I have to read one tag as string and pass it to another service.

Lets say I am getting this xml one time

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<inventory>
<header>
    <id>123</id>
</header>
 <book>
    <title>Snow Crash</title>
    <author>Neal Stephenson</author>
    <publisher>Spectra</publisher>
    <isbn>0553380958</isbn>
    <price>14.95</price>
 </book>
</inventory>
```

And I am also getting xml like this. The namespaces will be different. Its just for example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Category xmlns:in="uri.category.xsd.in.01">
<in:type>books</in:type>
<h:header xmlns:h="uri.header.xsd.01">
    <h:id>123</h:id>
    <h:memId>123</h:memId>
</h:header>
 <b:book xmlns:b="uri.books.xsd.01">
    <b:title>Snow Crash</b:title>
    <b:author>Neal Stephenson</b:author>
    <b:publisher>Spectra</b:publisher>
    <b:isbn>0553380958</b:isbn>
    <b:price>14.95</b:price>
 </b:book>
</Category>
```

NOTE : Every time I will get different xml's some with namespaces some without. But only thing common will be the two tags. Like in the above example header and book.

if I get first xml the I will send like this to the another service

```
<header>
    <id>123</id>
</header>
```

If i get the second xml as input then I am supposed to send this to the another service

```
<h:header xmlns:h="uri.header.xsd.01">
    <h:id>123</h:id>
    <h:memId>123</h:memId>
</h:header>
```

Note: This namespace is only for example. Now I am getting this namespace . I might get xmls with different namespaces only the header and book tag will be common not the namespace. Below might change for different xmls.

```
xmlns:h="uri.header.xsd.01"
```

I have solved this somehow using DOM parser and xpath.

I have written a method to get the namespace like in above case it is "h:" and doing some manipulation on string like below. I want to know if there is any better way to do this please.

```
public static String getNamespace(String s, Document doc) throws Exception{
    String ns="";
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(s,doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    Element element = (Element) nodeList.item(0);
    String elementwithNS = element.toString().substring(1,element.toString().length()-1);
    String namespace[]=elementwithNS.split(":");
    if(namespace.length==3)
        ns= namespace[0]+":";
    return ns;
}

ns_Header = getNamespace("//*[local-name()='header']");//I get the namespace as h:if it is empty then empty string 
String header_close_tag = "</"+ns_Header+"header>"
String header = StringUtils.substringBetween(xml,"header",header_close_tag);
String header_tag = "<"+ns_Header+"header"+header+header_close_tag;
```

I also want to read header tag values like id and memId. i am able to do that without namepsace but when namespace added that too the namespace keeps changing with different xmls. I am not sure how to read the tag values. Don't want to use JAXB since the XML I am using is quite big and I will end up creating multiple POJO based on different XMLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to extract the actual namespace. If you get your header element from your XPath expression, the namespace is still there. You only have to serialize the node to string.

Here is a complete example:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;

public class XmlExample {
  private static final String xmlWithoutNs = "<inventory>\n" +
    "<header>\n" +
    "    <id>123</id>\n" +
    "</header>\n" +
    " <book>\n" +
    "    <title>Snow Crash</title>\n" +
    "    <author>Neal Stephenson</author>\n" +
    "    <publisher>Spectra</publisher>\n" +
    "    <isbn>0553380958</isbn>\n" +
    "    <price>14.95</price>\n" +
    " </book>\n" +
    "</inventory>";

  private static final String xmlWithNs = "<Category xmlns:in=\"uri.category.xsd.in.01\">\n" +
    "<in:type>books</in:type>\n" +
    "<h:header xmlns:h=\"uri.header.xsd.01\">\n" +
    "    <h:id>123</h:id>\n" +
    "    <h:memId>123</h:memId>\n" +
    "</h:header>\n" +
    " <b:book xmlns:b=\"uri.books.xsd.01\">\n" +
    "    <b:title>Snow Crash</b:title>\n" +
    "    <b:author>Neal Stephenson</b:author>\n" +
    "    <b:publisher>Spectra</b:publisher>\n" +
    "    <b:isbn>0553380958</b:isbn>\n" +
    "    <b:price>14.95</b:price>\n" +
    " </b:book>\n" +
    "</Category>";

  private static String xmlToString(Node node) throws TransformerException {
    TransformerFactory fac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer;
    transformer = fac.newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(writer));
    return writer.toString();
  }

  private static String getHeaderAsString(Document doc) throws XPathExpressionException, TransformerException {
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/*/*[local-name() = 'header']");
    Node node = (Node) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
    return xmlToString(node);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory fac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    fac.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = fac.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document docWithNs = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlWithNs)));
    System.out.println("Example with Namespace:");
    System.out.println(getHeaderAsString(docWithNs));

    Document docWithoutNs = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlWithoutNs)));
    System.out.println("\nExample without Namespace:");
    System.out.println(getHeaderAsString(docWithoutNs));
  }
}
```

This is the output:

```
Example with Namespace:
<h:header xmlns:h="uri.header.xsd.01">
    <h:id>123</h:id>
    <h:memId>123</h:memId>
</h:header>

Example without Namespace:
<header>
    <id>123</id>
</header>
```

Comment: I had no idea on serialization of node to string. This is a better code. Thanks!